# X and Y axis on Arduino Serial Plotter?

Tags: arduino-uno, time

I am trying to plot my counter vs. time on the serial plotter, but the values on the y axis are so big there is no way that it's displaying the counter values.
I have printed both values:

```
  Serial.print("counter: ");
  Serial.println(counter);
  time = millis();
  Serial.print("Time: ");
  Serial.println(time);
```

I expected time to show up in the x-axis, but I think it's displaying on the y-axis and I'm not sure how to change this.
The plot should just be an increasing line as the counter and time get bigger...
what am I missing?
Thanks.

Slashing out the Serial.print("Time:") does not correct anything.

Answer (score 3):

Inorder to plot multiple variables or waveforms simultaneously a 'space' is printed between the two print statements.

```
Serial.print(counter);
Serial.print(" ");
time = millis();
Serial.println(time);
```

OR

```
Serial.print(counter);
Serial.print("\t");
time = millis();
Serial.println(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

Comment out the `Serial.print("Time: ");` line. The Arduino serial plotter wants only numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The X-axis is fixed and nothing gets plotted on the X-axis. It has its own divisions and they are automatically set by the Arduino IDE. The Arduino IDE still has to do some improvements to its software so that the X- axis can be adjusted and plotted too! This is my experience so far and corrections are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

To plot multiple values over time you need to output just the numbers on a single line per iteration, and delimit with a space or tab:

```
Serial.print(counter); 
Serial.print("\t"); // delimit with tab
time = millis();
Serial.print(time); 
Serial.println();
```

It's worth noting however, the time (x axis) is implied by each line. In essence each line of output advances "time" by 1 unit. So I suspect you'll want to remove the time variable output and just output the count variable by it self.